# Convenient public IPv6 test addresses

Tags: ipv6

Are there any convenient public, globally routable test addresses for IPv6?

Similar to how `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` tend to get used this way for IPv4?

Comment: It should be noted that pinging an arbitrary service on the Internet that you don't control is a crappy connectivity test.

Comment: It's an excellent positive test, but not really a good negative test.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The shortest I've seen is www.sprint.net (`2600::`).

Comment: Doesn't respond to UDP traceroute.

Comment: `64 bytes from 2600::: icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=207 ms`  - works

Comment: @Michael Lots of things don't respond to UDP traceroute these days. I tend to match the trace to the protocol in question (e.g. `nmap --traceroute` or `tcptraceroute` to port 80 for web servers.)

Comment: @MichaelHampton It does now.

Answer (score 11):

Handily enough, `2001:4860:4860::8888` and `2001:4860:4860::8844` are the IPv6 equivalents of `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`!

That's fairly easy to remember.

Comment: Works, but I would prefer them to be like `2001::8888` or even `2001::2001`

Comment: Strangely enough, [these are the IP addresses for Google Public DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using).

Comment: Not so strangely… that's where I got them from :)

Comment: @Vi. That wouldn't work. 2001::/32 is reserved to Teredo. Both of your suggestions would be using a Teredo server on the IPv4 address 0.0.0.0. But 0.0.0.0 wouldn't be a valid address for a Teredo server.

Answer (score 2):

`example.com`, `example.net`, and `example.org` are reserved domains for documentation purposes. However, they also resolve to a running HTTP server and can be opened in browser and this server also response to ping:

```
# ping -c1 example.net
PING example.net (93.184.216.34): 56 data bytes
...

# ping6 -c1 example.net
PING6(56=40+8+8 bytes) .... --> 2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946
...
```

The IP addresses are hard to remember, yet the domain names are easy, so if you have DNS...

Alternatively you can use the DNS servers of Quad9:
(great alternative to Google's DNS; better privacy and malware filtering)

```
# ping 9.9.9.9
# ping6 2620:fe::fe
```